# Is there a way to capture part of a screen in full screen mode?

Tags: screen-capture

I am playing a game that's called Bookworm on the Mac, and it runs in full screen mode.

If I press <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> to capture part of the screen, it won't work.  Usually, I can press <kbd>space</kbd> and click to capture the whole window, but that doesn't work, either.

<kbd>⇧ shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> works to capture the whole screen, but I'd like to find out how to take a partial screenshot.

Comment: cmd-shift-4 appears to work fine for me.  Tried in both iterm and itunes.  Could captured the selected rectangle just fine.  What happens when you hit cmd-shift-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> as usual. It just won't display its color overlay for the selection frame. The crosshair cursor should still show up and the screenshot should still be of the selected area.

Answer (score -1):

Check [SnappyApp](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/snappyapp/id512617038?mt=12) - is a very useful tool for screenshots for Mac OS, more powerful than the system screen capture functionality and it's free.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please see the help center regarding [self-promotion](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) and make sure you disclose if you are affiliated with a product.